# Read/Unread email option does not hold, reverts to Most Recent in Galaxy S3 4.1.1

Tags: email

I like to sort my email by read/unread on my Galaxy S3.  I could set that option in the sort by before I upgraded to 4.1.1.  It worked great before the upgrade.  Now it just reverts back to the Most Recent (by date) option.  I have to set it to sort by read/unread everytime I read my mail now.  Any ideas how to set a sort option which will stick?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on my S3 with Android version 4.1.2 (build number JZO54K.I9300XXEMC2). It might be a bug in Samsung's email client, which they fixed in the 4.1.2 update.